# Tight binding hamiltonian (semi empirical) for a doubly degenerate band

Tags: condensed-matter, tight-binding

For some monoclinic crystal, which has two atoms per unit cell, and its HOMO described by the doubly degenerate representation, E2u: how does one deduce the tight binding parameters from ab initio DFT data to describe the Hamiltonian for this band?

My confusion comes from the fact that my TB parameters look the same for both states of the degenerate band.

Would very much appreciate a brief explanation (I have spent a lot of time trying to answer the queston myself, apologies if this adds little value to the forum). Cheers.